# How to pull out a stuck third row seat on a Volvo XC90 MY2007?

Tags: volvo, seat, xc90

The left third row seat on a '07 Volvo XC90 is stuck underneath the collapsible backrest. Looking from the trunk from behind the seat, it seems to be stuck on the right rail, it won't budge at all. The seat seems as if it would move freely on the left rail.

After searching the internet for hours, I was only able to find info on how to fix a stuck backrest or headrest. To be clear, the backrest is working fine. I can lift it and I can collapse it. It's just the actual seat (the part where you put your bottom) that is stuck.

Any ideas what might cause it to remain fixed and how I can pull it out so that I may use that seat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 2007 Volvo XC90 when 3-rd row seat is collapsed, the bottom part of the seat is locked in place on the rails by two locks. When you lift the backrest up it pulls the cable which unlocks the left (looking from the trunk) lock. Left lock pulls the second cable which goes underneath the bottom part of the seat and it unlocks the right lock.

So if you have a problem with the left seat and the bottom part is stuck on the right rail, it means that something is wrong with the cable which goes underneath the bottom part of the seat. Maybe it's broken, or maybe the the end of the cable (which looks like a O-ring) felt of the pin on the lock.

Try to reach the cable underneath the seat and inspect it.

Comment: Any pointers on how I can reach this cable and where it is located? I can't fit my hand very far between the seat and the cover underneath and, try as I might, couldn't feel anything resembling a cable, let a lone inspect it. Isn't there any procedure in some service manual for this?